# Why do "skin effect" eddy currents not alternate between the skin and core?

Tags: electromagnetism

I understand the directions indicated in the diagram below, but only in the case of main current ($I$) increasing. Say that ($I$) is a sine wave, and the time is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$. This means ($I$) is still positive but is now decreasing, with magnetic field ($H$) doing the same. Wouldn't this cause the direction of eddy current ($Iw$) change, causing current to be biased toward the core, not the skin?

[image: diagram of currents and fields]